# Seaborn does not show legend with %matplotlib notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I use %matplotlib notebook, the legend is not displayed.

```
%matplotlib notebook
...
fg = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='Scenario', hue_order=df.Scenario.unique().tolist(), aspect=1.61)
fg.map(plt.scatter, 'Yaw', 'posNoseEye').add_legend()
```

[image]

While when I use %matplotlib inline, the legend is correctly shown.

```
%matplotlib inline
...
fg = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='Scenario', hue_order=df.Scenario.unique().tolist(), aspect=1.61)
fg.map(plt.scatter, 'Yaw', 'posNoseEye').add_legend()
```

[image]

How to manage it in %matplotlib notebook ?
Thanks

As I can't put image in the comment, I tried the answer below and it still does not work. 
I have the last version of matplotlib and  seaborn.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure does not have any space for the legend. There are several ways to overcome this, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317).

An option is to manually create some space for the legend, e.g.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2), columns=['Yaw', 'posNoseEye'])
df["Scenario"] = np.random.choice(["Scenario A","Scenario B"], size=20)

fg = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='Scenario', hue_order=df.Scenario.unique().tolist(), aspect=1.61)
fg.map(plt.scatter, 'Yaw', 'posNoseEye')

fg.fig.legend()

fg.fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not work. You can check the updated question with the last image.

Comment: That's the problem of missing [mcve]s. I now added one to the answer.

Comment: Your example work, the problem was in 

fg.map(plt.scatter, 'Yaw', 'posNoseEye').add_legend()

Delete .add_legend() -> working version

Comment: Yep true. There is a problem inside `add_legend` which appears when figures are only shown and not saved. I created a [Pullrequest on GitHub](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1328) for the issue.